# bash multiple email

Tags: php, bash

need a small help to send an email to 2 email addresses on finish script.

```
#!/bin/bash

DATA="date +%e-%m-%y"
SUBJET="Script executed $data"
EMAIL="email@email.com,email2@mail.com"

/usr/bin/php home/user/public_html/script1.php

sleep 60

/usr/bin/php home/user/public_html/script2.php

echo "data" | mail -s "$subjet" "$email"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/108371-how-can-i-send-mail-multiple-addresses-same-domain-bash.html

Comment: Hello Michael, you suggest to create a maillist="email1,email2,email3" ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the email addresses should be separated by whitespace, rather than comma.

also note, that bash variables are case-sensitive ($data != $DATA)

something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
DATE="$(date +%e-%m-%y)"
SUBJET="Script executed at ${DATE}"
EMAIL="email@email.com email2@mail.com"
echo "${DATE}" | mail -s "${SUBJET}" "${EMAIL}"
```

**UPDATE**

put the `date` into $(), so they get evaluated by bash

Comment: Actually many MTAs accept comma-separated recipients as well.

Comment: ah..true; i guess the problem is then with case sensitive variable names

Comment: So, in this case can i use both?, with comma and without? Thanks Allot

Comment: yes, is working, but the date is not returning the date... Thanks guys

Comment: yes, on this format is working, but on add the time stop the generating date: example: DATE=(date +"%d-%m-%Y %T")